# Unable to call variable defined in dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a data class as follows:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, Dict

raw_dir = r"C:..." # path of the raw dir
processed_dir = r"C:..." # path of the processed dir

@dataclass
class Files:
    raw_path: Path = Path(raw_dir)
    processed_path: Path = Path(processed_dir)

    path_dict: Dict[str, Any] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: {
            "raw_train_file": Path(raw_path, "raw_train.csv"),
            "processed_train_file": Path(processed_path, "processed_train.csv"),
        }
    )
Files().path_dict
```

This will throw an error `name "raw_path" is not defined.` But when you try to print `raw_path`  right after the first line, it can done and hence the problem may be from the `path_dict`. I tried replacing the key-value pair to `"raw": Path(directory)` and it worked so I do not think it is the issue with the data type.

---

Context: I treat the `dataclass` as a `config` file (func) such that when I need to call a default path, I can just use:

```py
pd.read_csv(Files().path_dict["raw_train_file"])
```

Comment: Where did you define `directory`? And what imports did you do?

Comment: The imports are not added to the post.

Comment: It's just late binding again, try `lambda r=raw_file: {"raw": r}`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, it worked, I am reading up on late binding here: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Would you ever actually use a _non_-default value there? A property might be more appropriate anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mind elaborating with an example of using a property here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What happens if I want to define two arguments inside the default dict?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. [Edit] the question to provide the context and a [mre] of what you're now stuck on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated my question, I tried to call 2 lambda arguments but did not work.

Comment: You haven't bound _either_ of them, why would it? You're back to the first problem, just 2x. And you still haven't answered my question about a non-default value or provided any context to the usage of this class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I provided a context for your review, apologies that I did not quite catch what you meant by `non-default` value. If I ever need to pass in a non-default value to the `path_dict`, I will try to do something like `Files(path_dict = {...})` when initialising.

Comment: But what would be the _point_ of that, given it now wouldn't match the other attributes? How does this actually get _used_?

Comment: @jonesharpe now I understood what you meant, as the path_dict depends on the first attribute. How would you suggest going about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the default_factory has to be a zero-argument callable. Because of that, it cannot use any member variable. Here, as the member variables have trivial initialization, you can repeat that initialization, to only use global vars:

```
...
path_dict: Dict[str, Any] = field(
    default_factory=lambda: {
        "raw_train_file": Path(Path(raw_dir), "raw_train.csv"),
        "processed_train_file": Path(Path(processed_dir), "processed_train.csv"),
    }
```

But you can also use the special `__post_init__` method which is called by the generated `__init__` after the other initialization. As it receive the `self` argument, it can use member variables:

```
@dataclass
class Files:
    raw_path: Path = Path(raw_dir)
    processed_path: Path = Path(processed_dir)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.path_dict: Dict[str, Any] = {
            "raw_train_file": Path(self.raw_path, "raw_train.csv"),
            "processed_train_file": Path(self.processed_path, "processed_train.csv"),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `functools.cached_property` to avoid neededing to define a `__post_init__` method in the dataclass. Note that I don't propose this to be a "better" solution in any way, only that's it another way to achieve the same goal.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import cached_property
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Dict

raw_dir = r"C:..."  # path of the raw dir
processed_dir = r"C:..."  # path of the processed dir


@dataclass
class Files:
    raw_path: Path = Path(raw_dir)
    processed_path: Path = Path(processed_dir)

    @cached_property
    def path_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            "raw_train_file": Path(self.raw_path, "raw_train.csv"),
            "processed_train_file": Path(self.processed_path, "processed_train.csv"),
        }


print(Files().path_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'raw_train_file': PosixPath('C:.../raw_train.csv'), 'processed_train_file': PosixPath('C:.../processed_train.csv')}
```